Correcting Matrices for Finite Metric Spaces
Suppose I have a $n\times n$ matrix $M$. Some of these matrices define a finite metric space, precisely when they obey these properties:

$M$ is symmetric;
$M$ has zeroes on the diagonal;
$M$ is positive outside the diagonal;
$M$ respects the triangle inequality, e.g. for all triples of indices $i,j,k$ we have
$$M_{ij} + M_{jk} \ge M_{ik} $$

We will call such matrices "fms" (from finite metric spaces). I am trying to write a "correct" algorithm to take any matrix and generate an fms matrix. It's easy to adjust for the first three conditions:

Replace $M$ with $(M+ M^T)/2$.
Replace the diagonal with zeroes.
Given $\varepsilon > 0$ and $m:= \min\{M_{ij}\}_{i,j \le n}$, replace $M_{ij} < 0$ with $ \varepsilon \cdot m$.

However, the last condition is harder. From now on, we suppose that our matrix obeys the first three conditions. Let us define a sequence of matrices in the following way: $M^{(0)} = M$, and
$$M^{(n+1)}_{ik} = \min_j M^{(n)}_{ij} + M^{(n)}_{jk} $$
Note $M^{(n)}_{ij}$ for fixed $i,j$ is a decreasing sequence of nonnegative numbers, thus converging to a number $M^{\infty}_{ij}$. The limiting matrix respect the triangle inequality. Indeed
$$M^{\infty}_{ik} = \min_j M^{\infty}_{ij} + M^{\infty}_{jk} $$
This implies that the minimum on the right-hand side is reached for $j=k$ (or $i$), and the other terms must be greater or equal to the left-hand side.
It's easy to see that $M^{\infty}$ is still symmetric, and has zeroes on the diagonal, but...

Can new zeroes pop up? How can we handle this exception?

For example, we could use step (3) above for the substitution, but it's unclear whether the matrix still respects triangle inequality. And what if we repeat the limiting step after the $\varepsilon$-replacement? But the real question is the following:

Does the limiting process always end in a finite number of steps?

From my limited simulations, it seems like there is a bound on the number of steps in terms of the size of the matrix, but it seems like a very hard problem. A partial result in small dimensions (e.g. $n=2, 3,4$) would be nice to start.

Thinking about this construction as a limit is obscuring what's going on. What you are doing is interpreting the input matrix $M_{ij}$ as a matrix of, say, lengths of edges on a graph, then constructing the path metric of this graph; that is, $M^{\infty}_{ij}$ is just the length of the shortest path between $i$ and $j$. (So computing it means solving the all-pairs shortest path problem.)
The shortest path between two vertices on a graph with $n$ vertices travels through at most $n-1$ edges (because the shortest path never needs to repeat vertices), and your construction actually has the property that $M^{(k)}_{ij}$ is the length of the shortest path traveling through at most $2^{k-1}$ edges (each iteration considers paths consisting of two paths from the previous iteration so doubles the possible number of edges), so actually this iteration stabilizes after at most $\log_2 n$ iterates or so.
It's also clear from this point of view that no new zeroes can pop up because the shortest path is at least as long as the shortest edge. In terms of your matrix construction the minimum you're taking can never get smaller than $\text{min}_{i \neq j} \,  M_{ij}$ (off the diagonal, of course).

Thanks,  thinking in terms of the path metric on the complete graph is what I thought later in the day. It does shed light on the problem, and also gives a more efficient algorithm - even better, an already implemented one!
